# How to test JavaScript code that references a html element in a html file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, jsdom

I am new to JavaScript and its testing libraries. I have been trying to run a unit test using mocha, chai and JSDOM.I have tried different resources to learn, but none explains in a way that is easy to understand for a beginner. I came up with a simple test. I know i have done a lot of things wrong in the test and am hoping someone can help on how to do the test or even a nice resource that covers my need.

my test

```
const {JSDOM} = require('jsdom');
const dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>');

global.window = dom.window;
global.document = dom.window.document;


const Auths = require('../UI/js/login.js')
auth = Auths("sammy@gmail.com","sa!@##$")


var assert = require('chai').assert;
describe('Login', function() {
  it('should return a wrong email or password for invalid login', function() {

    assert.equal(document.getElementById("erroMessage").value,"wrong email or password")

  });
});
```

The code that am trying to test

```
class Auths {

  constructor(email,password) {
    this.email = email
    this.password = password

  }


  // this function is called when the litsener responds to submit eve
  login(){


    // url for endpoint
    let url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v2/users/login"

    // get login data from ui
    let data = {
      email : this.email,
      password : this.password
    };



    // define data to be used in options section
    let fetchData = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body:JSON.stringify(data)

    };

    // use the fetch api
    fetch(url,fetchData)
    .then(function(response){return response.json()})
    .then(function(response){

      // store data fore use after login
      localStorage.setItem('token',response.token);
      localStorage.setItem('role',response.role);
      localStorage.setItem('names',response.names);

      // login the user
      if(response.message === "wellcome "+response.names +", "+"you are loged in as "+response.role){

        // login admin
        if(response.role == "admin"){
          window.location.href = 'UI/Admin/admin.html';
        }

        // login store attendant
        else{
          window.location.href = 'UI/Attendant.html';
        }
      }

      // respond to wrong cridentials
      else {
        document.getElementById("erroMessage").innerHTML = response.message;
      }

    })
  }

}

let login = document.getElementById('login');
login.addEventListener('submit', function getTarget(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  let email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  let password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  auth = new Auths(email, password);
  auth.login();
})

module.exports = Auths;
```

The error i have encountered

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
>       at Object. (A:\sammy\New folder\ADC1-ADC4_Store_Manager\UI\js\login.js:70:7)

Answer (score 1):

The elements on your page are not defined.  You can write them to the document in the test.  See the changed code below.  However, you really want to call auth.login() which results in an error with fetch inside of login.js.  So I would consider looking at a mocking framework where you can mock calls and responses so that you can verify that your response logic works.

```
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
const dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>');
const assert = require('assert');

global.window = dom.window;
global.document = dom.window.document;
global.document.write('<button type="button" id="login"> Login</button >')
global.document.write('<input id="erroMessage" value="wrong email or password">')

const Auths = require('../js/login.js')
auth = new Auths("sammy@gmail.com", "sa!@##$")

describe('Login', function () {
    it('should return a wrong email or password for invalid login', function () {
        assert.equal(document.getElementById("erroMessage").value, "wrong email or 
          password")
    });
});
```